# Retrieve the second Date Value as part of Measure based on Filters

Tags: powerbi, dax

https://1drv.ms/t/s!AjQUxa0vBJvUh-VxNRGjs3TJ-AXxsQ?e=Bv0S1N

**Sample data here:**

```
Date        Item1, Item2, Percentage, NCount

05/20/2023    T1     P1       100%       10
05/21/2023    T2     P2        90%        9
05/21/2023    T1     P1        90%        9
05/22/2023    T1     P1        80%        8
05/22/2023    T1     P1         0%        0  <--first occurrence
**05/24/2023  T1     P1         0%        0**    <-- This data to be retrieved 
05/24/2023    T2     P2         0%        0   <--first occurrence
**05/26/2023  T2     P2         0%        0**  <-- This data to be retrieved
```

Attached is the sample data, but above is also simple one to try out.

Looking to retrieve the second 0 or 0% associated Date as part of Measure ( filtered by Item1 and Item2)

I am drawing a line chart and want this measure to draw a vertical line. I can only draw only if i can get this second occurrence 0 instance date.

Answer (score 0):

This should return the next date with an NCount of 0 for `Item1` and `Item2` following the first record containing an NCount of 0 for the same `Item1` and `Item2`. This expects that only one `Item1` and `Item2` will be passed to it (via row context). If multiple are passed to it, it will evaluate them as a group.

```
FIRSTNONBLANK (
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        OFFSET (
            1,
            FILTER ( ALLEXCEPT ( data, data[Item1], data[Item2] ), data[NCount] = 0 ),
            ORDERBY ( [Date], ASC )
        ),
        "Date", [Date]
    ),
    [Date]
)
```

To return a different value from the data table from the desired record, just change the `SELECTCOLUMNS()` and `FIRSTNONBLANK()` arguments.

To find records where both `Percentage` *or* `NCount` are 0, simply append `|| data[Percentage] = 0` after `data[NCount] = 0`.

Comment: @kenwhite, did this solve your question?